# You have an error in your SQL syntax ...near '''

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

[image]
Here is my table.

Trying to make a "forgot password form."

Getting the same error over and over. Need your help.

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''' at line 1`

Here's my code.

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim con As New MySqlConnection("host=localhost; username=root; database= login")
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader

    con.Open()
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText = "select 'from users where userID= ' " & userTxt.Text & " ' and secretQ = ' " & qTxt.Text & " 'and answer= ' " & ansTxt.Text & "' "
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader


    If Not dr Is Nothing Then
        dr.Read()
        pwTxt.Text = dr(2)
        dr.Close()
    Else
        MsgBox("Invalid Username or Password.")

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Your query is wide open to SQL injection, amongst other problems.

Comment: whats that tick doing in front of `from`?  Never concat SQL, use Parameters.  Try a user name of `D'Angelo`  and never store passwords as plaintext - hash them

Comment: It is worth noting that this is an awful way of doing this. If you have any kind of user input in this, you are open to having SQL injections dropped on you (hehehe drop, like drop table).

Comment: Im voting to close this question because its a typo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a quote in your sql query , remove it

```
select 'from users
       ^
```

You should also use parameterized queries. Not only it will prevent SQL injection, but also escape characters in your values such as quotes for example.

Example:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select from users 
                   where userID= @userID 
                         and secretQ = @secretQ 
                         and answer= @answer"

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userID ", userTxt.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@secretQ", qTxt.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@answer", ansTxt.Text)

dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
```

To be explicit:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@userID", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userTxt.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@secretQ", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = qTxt.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@answer", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ansTxt.Text
```